# Since adding HTTP security headers, Ahrefs.com produces JS 404s

Tags: http-headers

We're using WP Engine for our website host. I added some Web Rules to produce the following HTTP headers:

```
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin
Feature-Policy: geolocation 'self'
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
```

Since making the change above, the next Ahrefs.com Site Audit produced a lot of 404s for some Beaver Builder JS files.

If you load the webpage where that 404 is detected by Ahrefs, then there are no broken resources.

It is only the Ahrefs user agents which are generating the 404 for some Beaver Builder JS files.

Could the HTTP headers added above be producing these 404s by the Ahrefs user agent?

WP Engine say the Ahrefs user agents are not blocked.

Help appreciated.

**Update**: in the Ahrefs crawl settings, turning on "Execute Javascript " resolved this issue for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago Arefs announced rendering web pages and executing JavaScript for its [Crawler](https://ahrefs.com/blog/crawling-javascript/) and for [Site Audit tool](https://ahrefs.com/blog/site-audit-crawls-javascript/).

To do this, Ahrefs had to partially implement browser rendering. This was not a full-fledged browser implemented, but some part of its "ready to use" code was taken. This renderer, inherited partial support of HTTP headers, which was built into this "ready-to-use" code.
But the main task was to search for links inserted via javascript, and not full support for HTTP headers.

Therefore, the implementation used incorrectly executes some headers, which one it can only be found out by experimenting - disable them one by one and wait for the results.
But these are hardly headers `Referrer-Policy`, `Feature-Policy` and `X-Frame-Options` - they cannot result in a `404 Not Found` error.

Most likely, these are just an Ahrefs renderer errors of loading external scripts, they are unlikely to have an impact on the analysis capabilities of Ahrefs or SE ranking.